# Send Notifications from Service Worker just whether it has permission

Tags: javascript, notifications, service-worker

I've the following problem: I'm working in a web application that send notification to the user using Notification API. These  notifications are send from Service Worker because we need to get the datas from the server.

I've checked that Notification object doesn't have the permission property in SW context. My doubt is: is there any way to check whether the application have permission to send Notification in SW context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, no, you cannot explicitly check that the user has granted permission through an API like Notification (in window context).

What you could do for instance is:

- When user grants permission, store that information to either to Caches or IndexedDB; check that when you would like to show a notification (both of these storages are available in window and SW)
- When you want to show a notification, ask the page if the user has granted the permission; you would do this via postMessage API and you would have to register a listener both in the page and the SW